# Scope and OR operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, this, logical-operators

I walked on something weird while doing some JS code today.

I wanted to execute an object's method if the property existed, and some other function if it didn't.
Feeling a little bit fancy, I wrote something like:

```
var obj = {
    method: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

(obj.method || some_other_function)();
```

This executes `obj.method` if it exists, and `some_other_function` otherwise.

But **the `this` keyword refers to the `window` Object when obj.method is executed**, and I have absolutely no idea why.
Note that executing `(obj.method)();` gives the expected result (this referring to my object)

Obviously I don't *need* this syntax to make my code run, but I really wonder what's happening here.

I couldn't find any answer either here or elsewhere, the closest thing I found is [this interesting post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/), but it doesn't cover this specific case.

Anyone knows what's happening there?

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikake/bhpe78Ln/5/) showing the thing in action!

Comment: I would recommend reading this (long-ish but well explained) : https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Comment: Thanks for the link! I try to read stuff, watch things, and I kind of find my way when I code, but JS definitely has some very specific features!  This article seems very detailed, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(obj.method || some_other_function)();` is, essentially, the same as:

```
var f = obj.method || some_other_function;
f();
```

You've taken the function away from the context of `obj` by running it through *or* before you call it.

Comment: You also need to explain why `(obj.method)();` is not the same as `var f = obj.method; f();` ;)

Comment: Ouch, I might have misunderstood the ' this ' keyword... I had never played with execution context until now, and this could explain some weird other bugs I have encountered in JS o_O
Thank you for this clear and concise explanation!

( that was a kind of noobish first-question on SO :)

Comment: @plalx I guess that parenthesis without some operator don't change the expression it contains, and therefore there is no implicit intermediate variable? I admit I didn't figure it out at the beginning tho ( that's indeed why I wrote `(obj.method)();` as a comparison :)

Answer (score 0):

`obj.method()` is syntactic sugar for

```
method.call(obj)
```

Also known as a **method** invocation (which is different from invoking a **function**). If the property (`method`) is used in any other way it returns a function value. Eg. using it in a binary operation such as

```
(obj.method || some_other_function)()
```

makes it a *function value* and the above expression is syntactic sugar for

```
(obj.method || some_other_function).call(this)
```

`this` is then the current context and not `obj`.

`(obj.method)()` is still a method invocation since `(expression)` and `expression` are treated equal

Comment: Thanks, indeed I hadn't noticed that my `||` was creating an implicit variable, And I also didn't realise that you could turn a method into a function, (I almost only use the scope to isolate stuff, nothing more) and this problem helped me a lot!

Comment: Awesome edit, I'm only beginning to play with all these `call` , `bind`, `apply` ... properties, and I now greatly understand the `call` ! Now I clearly know **why** the `this`keyword is different. It's the eternal trouble of high level languages, you have to learn all what happens under the hood as a counterpart of not having to reinvent everything..!

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is very common for people learning JavaScript and stems from an incomplete understanding of `this`. The short answer is that your code is either executing `obj.method()` or `some_other_function()`. The context of `this` inside of an invoked function refers to the object that invoked that function. In a typical use case of calling the `method` function (simply calling `obj.method()`), `obj` invokes `method` and so `this` refers to `obj` in the function block.

However, the expression `(obj.method || some_other_function)()` doesn't appear to be invoked by any object, it's just...invoked, right? What's actually happening is that this expression is called from the global space, which, in the browser, is the `window` object. So you can think of your code as being executed like this:

```
obj : {
    method: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

window.(obj.method || some_other_function)();
```

Both `some_other_function` and `obj.method` are invoked from the global space because they are evaluated as an expression inside of your || conditional block. That expression is actually just a property on the `window` object, and that is what is invoking it. I was confused about this too at first, very interesting problem and thanks to Quentin for the correct answer.

Here is a great blog post that helps clarify `this` in JavaScript: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Edited: I've updated this post to reflect the correct answer, my original answer was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Travis, but the problem was really only about the `obj.method` in which `this` was referring to the `window` object. As @Quentin pointed out, it's because my logical OR operation sort of takes the `method` out of `obj` (see his answer)   so the `this` keyword is actually the window.

Comment: And this shows that even people (me) who think they have a good understanding of `this` still get confused :)

Comment: I thought I did too, don't worry ;)